# What's the surface area of the outlined figure on the sphere and the volume of the outlined figure in the ball.

Tags: geometry

[image]

All the sides are radiuses and angle radians. Please try to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates?

Comment: Hint: Describe in radians the angle of the blue zones, then apply triple integrals with spherical coordinates.

Comment: hint transform it all to  the unit sphere ( a sphere where the radius = 1, and study how to find the surface on this sphere)

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it, you have an *equilateral triangle* on the sphere, with all edges having *arc length* $R$. I'll base my answer on this.

For simplicity, consider the case of $R=1$, i.e. the unit sphere. Using the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) you can compute the interior angles of this spherical triangle as

$$\alpha=\arccos\frac{\cos(1)-\cos(1)^2}{\sin(1)^2}\approx 1.2124$$

Now the area of a spherical triangle on the unit sphere [is equal to its excess angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess), so you get

$$A=3\alpha-\pi\approx0.4956$$

And since surface area and sector volume are proportional, and the volume of the whole unit sphere is $\frac43\pi$ while its area is $4\pi$, you obtain the volume as

$$V=\frac A3=\alpha-\frac\pi3\approx0.1652$$

If you have $R\neq1$ then you have to multiply $A$ by $R^2$ and $V$ by $R^3$.